# CMake Option to Disable Compilation on Specific Files for Specific Platforms

Tags: c++, cross-platform, cmake

I am using CMake to define my projects.  My goal is to have platform-specific files easily accessible for editing, searching, browsing, and source control with across all platforms.

I currently have platform-specific files separated in the cmake description.  My CMakeLists.txt file looks something like the following:

```
 Foo.hpp
 ${platform_directory}/Foo.cpp
```

Then on disk I have something like this:

```
 Foo.hpp
 win
  `- Foo.cpp 
 osx
  `- Foo.cpp
```

Which in the generated project file looks like:

```
 Foo.hpp
 Foo.cpp (platform-specific version)
```

This is perfect for the compiler, but it means that developers lack IDE tooling for non-native platform-specific files.

What I am looking for is something like this (in Xcode):

```
 Foo.hpp
 Foo.cpp (OS X version)
 win
  `- Foo.cpp (file type set to plain text)
```

Or in Visual Studio:

```
 Foo.hpp
 Foo.cpp (Windows version)
 osx
  `- Foo.cpp (build action set to none)
```

Any ideas on how something like this can be setup CMake?

Comment: Adding them to source group might help: http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:source_group

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to add a custom target with no build rules, specifically to hold the files which aren't part of the given platform's build;  e.g.

```
if(WIN32)
  add_library(Foo Foo.hpp win/Foo.cpp)
  add_custom_target(NonWindows SOURCES osx/Foo.cpp)
  source_group("osx" osx/Foo.cpp)
else(APPLE)
  add_library(Foo Foo.hpp osx/Foo.cpp)
  add_custom_target(NonApple SOURCES win/Foo.cpp)
  source_group("win" win/Foo.cpp)
endif()
```

Another option (perhaps closer to what you want, but a bit more "hacky") is to add all the files to the target, but mark the ones not required for the build as `HEADER_FILE_ONLY`:

```
add_library(Foo Foo.hpp win/Foo.cpp osx/Foo.cpp)
if(WIN32)
  set_source_files_properties(osx/Foo.cpp PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE)
  source_group("osx" osx/Foo.cpp)
else(APPLE)
  set_source_files_properties(win/Foo.cpp PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE)
  source_group("win" win/Foo.cpp)
endif()
```

Answer (score 3):

The HEADER_FILE_ONLY [technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703044/472698) suggested by [Fraser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2556117/fraser) works great, but explicitly configuring which files should be complied on which platform gets tedious.

Given a CMake function as follows:

```
function (DisableCompilingPlatformSpecificSources file_list)
   foreach(file ${file_list})
      if (
         ((${file} MATCHES "^(.*)Win32\\.cpp") AND NOT WIN32) OR
         ((${file} MATCHES "^(.*)Unix\\.cpp")  AND NOT UNIX)  OR
         ((${file} MATCHES "^(.*)Apple\\.cpp") AND NOT APPLE)
      )
         set_source_files_properties(
            ${file}
            PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE
         )
      endif()
   endforeach()
endfunction()
```

We can control platform-specific sources by means of their suffix.  For example:

```
set(all_sources
   Foo.hpp
   FooWin32.cpp # windows-specific
   FooApple.cpp # apple-specific
)

DisableCompilingPlatformSpecificSources("${all_sources}")

add_executable(foo ${all_sources})
```

This is quite similar to how [gyp](https://code.google.com/p/gyp/) handles [platform-specific files](https://code.google.com/p/gyp/wiki/GypUserDocumentation#Add_new_source_files) and can be easily extended to support additional suffixes as needed.